# Fullpage.js: How to add css class "active" to slide anchor

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I added the "active" class to my entries of a menu so highlight which section is currently selected. Is it possible to add this also for slides?

Version: 2.6.4

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using fullPage.js slides callbacks to do so, for example:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({    
    afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index) {
        //section 2 loaded
        if (index == 2) {
            //adding active class to the 1st element in the slide menu
            $('#myMenu').find('li').eq(0).addClass('active');
        }
    },

    //
    afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {

        //only for slides in section 2
        if (index == 2) {
            $('#myMenu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            $('#myMenu').find('li').eq(slideIndex).addClass('active');
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/542/)

Or, if you prefer, the class fullPage.js adds to the body element of your site which is of the kind `fp-viewing-sectionAnchor-slideAnchor`. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M).

```
body.fp-viewing-1-0 #myMenu .first{
    background: yellow;
}
```

[Demo online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/541/)

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem and with that new idea I added some other features to my page ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
.fp-viewing-1 ul#menu li:nth-child(1) a
```

This is relatively simple with css:

1. Get the current body class: i.e. `fp-viewing` and whatever it shows
2. Add the nth child where you want to display active in your menu.

Comment: A far more elegant solution to get the same result, thanks!