# Fullpage.js navbar active on slides not sections

Tags: fullpage.js

Hi everyone just started learning Fullpage.js here and i was wondering if i can let's say divide my page into 3 sections 1 for header 1 for section and 1 for footer. Then set 4-5 sliders in the Section part. what i want is for the navbar to highlight only the current slider in that section not all 4-5 of them at once...
like so:[image: Header section]

Then when i go to the sections it does this:
[image: Section]

and the last section:
[image]

how do i make it only active on the current slider and not all of them?
Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of the [fullPage.js state classes](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) for that. Probably the easiest way.

Using the `fp-viewing-x-y` class added to the `body` should be quite easy. For example:

```
.fp-viewing-home-0 #menu li:nth-child(1){
    background:red;
}
.fp-viewing-home-1 #menu li:nth-child(2){
    background:red;
}
.fp-viewing-home-2 #menu li:nth-child(3){
    background:red;
}
```

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1824/)

If you prefer to use jQuery or JavaScript, you can make use of fullpage.js callbacks such as `onLeave`. 
See [another of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29768470/1081396) and the [example online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/542/).